# OS X and FSEvents: How do you release a callback pointer supplied to an FSEventStreamRef?

Tags: callback, objective-c-blocks, fsevents, toll-free-bridging

I'm using FSEvents to monitor a directory, and whenever the directory changes I call a block which I originally passed into the FSEventStreamContext of the FSEventStreamRef. How do I release the block when it is time to stop monitoring the directory?  Code below for reference.

```
void fsevents_callback(ConstFSEventStreamRef streamRef, void *clientCallBackInfo, size_t numEvents, void *eventPaths, const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[], const FSEventStreamEventId eventIds[]) {
    void (^block)() = (__bridge void (^)())(clientCallBackInfo);
    block();
}

- (FSEventStreamRef)startObserving:(NSString *)path block:(void(^)())block {
    void *ptr = (void *)CFBridgingRetain(block);  // NOTE: the block is retained
    FSEventStreamContext context = { 0, ptr, NULL, NULL, NULL };
    FSEventStreamRef stream = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL, fsevents_callback, &context, (__bridge CFArrayRef)@[path], kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow, 10, kFSEventStreamCreateFlagUseCFTypes | kFSEventStreamCreateFlagIgnoreSelf);
    FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(stream, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    FSEventStreamStart(stream);
    return stream;
}

- (void)stopObserving:(FSEventStreamRef)stream {
    // HELP: the block should be released here. can I get it through FSEvents?
    FSEventStreamStop(stream);
    FSEventStreamInvalidate(stream);
    FSEventStreamRelease(stream);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to release blocks; at least I've never seen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FSEventStreamContext` has member variables for functions to retain and release  the `info` pointer, which in your example is your `void *` block pointer.

Via [Apple's FSEvents reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004723-CHFSEventshDataTypes-DontLinkElementID_10):

```
retain
  The callback used retain the info pointer. This can be NULL.

release
  The callback used release a retain on the info pointer. This can be NULL.
```

First, retain. Since you need to cast the block to `void *` for `FSEventStreamContext` anyway, I think it's fine to continue using `CFBridgingRetain()` in your `startObserving:` method. No retain callback function is needed.

For release, try this callback function:

```
void release_callback(const void *info) {
    CFBridgingRelease(info);
}
```

Then try changing your `FSEventStreamContext` declaration to:

```
    FSEventStreamContext context = { 0, ptr, NULL, release_callback, NULL };
```

That should release your block when `stopObserving:` is called.

Comment: Thanks! I totally did not pay attention to those two variables of FSEventStreamContext.

Comment: So guys, will you please tell me how does the code go there for releasing ??